# Jest cleaning up of Express server settings

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm playing around with a side practice software, and I'm trying to learn how to use Jest for testing. But I get an error when it should clean up the testing suite, I suspect because of async code.

When I run the Jest CLI with --runInBand, it works great, but I want to understand and fix so it will work without the flag.
\

Example of one of the test files

```
const {Genre} = require('../../../models/genre');
const {mongoose} = require('../../../app');
const request = require('supertest');
let server;

describe('testing GET for genres', function() {
    beforeEach( function()  {
        server = require('../../../app').server;
    });
    afterEach(async function() {
        await Genre.deleteMany({});
        await mongoose.connection.close();
        server.close();
    });

    it('should create a genre',async function() {
       let genre = {
           name: "abcde"
       };
        const result = await request(server).post('/api/genres').send(genre);
         return expect(result).toBeDefined();
    }) ;
});
```

Example of the other one:

```
const {User} = require('../../../models/user');
const request = require('supertest');
const {mongoose} = require('../../../app');
let server;

describe('testing POST for users', function() {
   beforeEach(function()  {
      server = require('../../../app').server;
   });

   afterEach(async function() {
      await User.deleteMany({});
      await mongoose.connection.close();
      server.close();
   });

   it('should create a user',async function() {
      let user = {
         email: "testing123@gmail.com",
         password: "Yoyoyoy"
      };
      const result = await request(server).post('/api/users').send(user);
      expect(result.status).toBe(200);
      expect(result.body).toHaveProperty("email", "testing123@gmail.com");
      expect(result.body).toHaveProperty("isAdmin", false);

   }) ;
});
```

And when I run npm test, On of the 2 tests fail, and I get the error that the server is already running and also the error that I tried to do stuff/log after jest was shut down. Cleary this is a sync issue, can anyone help me to understand why, and how to control this?